# Apache prefolk module cannot run concurrently with php7.2 module

Tags: apache, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

**1.Environment**

Uname 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

PHP 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli)

**2.Problem**

I use the a2dismod command to close the mpm_prefolk and php7.2 modules, continue to use a2enmod to open the mpm_event module, open the event successfully, but after I continue to try to open the php7.2 module, an error occurred.

[Operation process & ErrorCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrBzG.png)

So I just turned off mpm_prefolk and then opened php7.2 as it said, php7.2 loaded successfully, but it automatically loaded the mpm_prefolk module.

[Operation process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT9Sw.png)

But at this time, the mpm_event module cannot be loaded.

[ErrorCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJK6u.png)

It needs to let me close mpm_prefolk,Just like an infinite loop, I don't know if I should reinstall the php environment or apache server, or php7.2 can only work with apache mpm_prefolk working mode, so I can only temporarily change it back.

**3.Solution & Analyze**

I solved the problem by reinstall the suit of php and apache ,and i read the apache documentation. So i found that apache mod_php only spport the prefolk module. You must install the php fpm Module

Comment: Try restarting the Apache service.

--> systemctl restart apache2

Comment: No effect, especially after closing the mpm_prefolk module, apache will can not restart.